# How to retrieve values from an object to put it in an array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

For several hours now, I've been trying to figure out how to get the value of an object in Angular.

At first, I thought it wasn't an object but I have ran this line and it show me that :

```typescript
console.log(typeof(Fruits));
```

And I got this answer :

```console
fruits.component.ts:143 object
```

So now, I'm sure it is an object. I've searched online and found some way to do it like :

```typescript
Object.values(Fruits)
// or
Object.keys(Fruits)
// or
Fruits.item_text
```

But it didn't work (maybe I misused them).

So I decided to print the object directly to see what is on this object :

```typescript
console.log(Fruits);
```

And then I got this :

```console
fruits.component.ts:144 (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]0: {item_id: 1, item_text: "Banana"}1: {item_id: 2, item_text: "Apple"}2: {item_id: 3, item_text: "Orange"}3: {item_id: 4, item_text: "Pear"}4: {item_id: 5, item_text: "Peach"}5: {item_id: 6, item_text: "Pineapple"}length: 6__proto__: Array(0)
```

My goal is to get every 'item_text' in an array :

```console
["Banana", "Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "Peach", "Pineapple"]
```

If this question is really basic, I'm sorry.

P.S : I'm running Angular 10.0.7 and TypeScript 3.9.7

Comment: The easiest way to get a `console.log` of an unknown structure is `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2))`. As long as there aren't circular references, you'll get a nicer display of the object.

Comment: `typeof` is sketchy in JavaScript. As you would expect, `typeof {} === 'object'`, but also `typeof [] === 'object'`, and even more bafflingly, `typeof null === 'object'`. To check `Fruits` is an array, you can instead use `Array.isArray(Fruits)` or `Fruits instanceof Array`.

Comment: That's really interesting, thanks for this. I can now see that it is an array for sure, not an object !
Also, thanks for editing my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the `Fruits` is an array. You could use Array [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to get single properties from object elements as an array.

Try the following

```js
fruitNames = [];
...

this.fruitNames = this.Fruits.map(fruit => fruit['item_text']);
```

```js
let Fruits = [ {item_id: 1, item_text: "Banana"}, {item_id: 2, item_text: "Apple"}, {item_id: 3, item_text: "Orange"}, {item_id: 4, item_text: "Pear"}, {item_id: 5, item_text: "Peach"}, {item_id: 6, item_text: "Pineapple"} ]

let fruitNames = Fruits.map(fruit => fruit['item_text'])
console.log(fruitNames);
```

#### Why `typeof(Fruits)` shows `object`

In Javascript, instances of classes `Object`, `Array`, `Map`, `Set`, `WeakMap`, `Set`, and `Date` are considered *special* types and holds true for the statement `typeof instance === "object"`. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures).

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for. But how did you know that is was an array ?

Comment: @Errias10: Many indications: the output is of the form `[{}, {}, ...]`. The square brackets denote the array. Also the numbering before each element: `0: {}, 1: {}, ..`. They denote the id of each element in the array.

Comment: Okay, so the `fruits.component.ts:143 object` doesn't mean anything or it's for something else ?

Comment: @Errias10: I've updated the answer to include an explanation for the type `object`.

Comment: That's going to help a lot of people for sure, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example:

```js
const arr = [{item_id: 1, item_text: "Banana"}, {item_id: 2, item_text: "Apple"}, {item_id: 3, item_text: "Orange"}, {item_id: 4, item_text: "Pear"}, {item_id: 5, item_text: "Peach"}, {item_id: 6, item_text: "Pineapple"}];

const result = arr.map((item) => item.item_text);

console.log(result);
```